# Login failed for user 'sa' in ms sql linux container

Tags: sql-server, docker-compose

I am using windows laptop and installed docker desktop and created a docker compose file and I am able to run it succesfully and it creates the images but when i try to connect to that sql server using my laptops ssms it is not allowing me to do so and giving error 'login failed for user 'sa'

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "1.0"
services:
    sqlserver:
        # load the sql server image from microsoft registry
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
        environment: 
          - SA_PASSWORD=Password@1
          - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        ports:
          - "1433:1433"
        volumes:
            # copy the sql scripts to container
          - ..\..\SQL Scripts\Initial Creation Script.sql:/var/scripts/Initial Creation Script.sql
        command:
          - /bin/bash
          - -c 
          - |
            # Launch MSSQL and send to background
            /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
            sleep 30
            /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P $$SA_PASSWORD -l 30 -e -i '/var/scripts/Initial Creation Script.sql'       #<== here I am just creating a db and some tables in it
            #done
            # So that the container doesn't shut down, sleep this thread
            sleep infinity
```

when i go to terminal of this container in docker desktop I am able to login using 'sa' with the same password using `sqlcmd` utility and I see that it has created my DB and tables as well

see below screenshot
[image]

I am not sure what is wrong with this. this was working in my old laptop and now I got a new laptop and everything is broken, obviusly this is not the reason

some facts:
In this laptop I already have a 'sa' user (on localhost) with different password, is that hampering this?!! , if yes how can i create a special user for my docker image only with `sys` access for my database `fithub`, may be something like `FithubDBUser` with some custom password, can i do it in docker compose file?

thank you

Comment: Check the logs within the container and get the *true* authentication error. If you don't understand that error, then [edit] your question to include that error.

Comment: *"In this laptop I already have a 'sa' user (on localhost) with different password"* so do you have an instance of SQL Server on the host, running on port 1433 *and* an instance on Docker which you want to forward connections on port 1433 on the *host* to the container? You can't do that. If you want to have both a docker and local instance one needs to be on a different port. Either the localhost needs to be on a different port or you need to forward a different port to the container's port (1433).

Comment: I'm wondering why `docker compose up` doesn't throw an error if you try to bind a port which is already in use for your local sql server. But yes,that local instance probably is the problem. Try using a different port on the host machine for your container, ie something like `- "1434:1433"`. This will map your port 1434 on the hostmachine to port 1433 in the container and you should be able to connect to the SQL instance in the container with `localhost:1434` ...

Comment: Indeed. If you already have another SQL Server instance (or Docker container) listening on 1433 then you should have gotten an error along the lines of `(container_id): Bind for 0.0.0.0:1433 failed: port is already allocated` when trying to start it.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that you can successfully connect to it from anything (even from inside the container). As per the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) you need to pass in the sa password in using the `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` environment variable. It used to be just `SA_PASSWORD` but hasn't been that for quite a while now.

Comment: thank you @ThomA, @derpirscher, @AlwaysLearning there was an issue with port only, when I mapped (today morning) `1434:1433` it worked. Moreover I was looking at the logs from yesterday, the container was anyway mapping it to 1434 yesterday.. see the logs from yesteday `2023-06-15 10:16:14.20 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].
2023-06-15 10:16:14.20 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port 1434.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the answer from the comments, thanks to all the commentors, I already had localhost listening on my local laptop on 1433, and that instance also had `sa` user (with different password),  so it was not getting connected, when I changed my `docker-compose.yml` file to map it to a different port it worked.

Here is the edited `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "1.0"
services:
    sqlserver:
        # load the sql server image from microsoft registry
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
        environment: 
          - SA_PASSWORD=Password@1
          - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        ports:
          - "1434:1433"
```

I will mark this question as answered. Somehow another question is popping up in my head,

> how can we gauge what ports will be in use on host machine, it might
> happen 1434 is also getting used? but I will do some research and if
> needed will post here